# Restrict the length with the help of directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, attributes, directive, maxlength

I wanted to add a custom directive as attribute which will not allow user to enter text in placeholder more than specified length

```
   <ui-select-match placeholder="Add one..." maxlength></ui-select-match>
```

The new directive can be like "maxlength" which will restrict the length of text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<textarea my-maxlength="15" ng-model="result"></textarea>

app.directive('myMaxlength', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      var maxlength = Number(attrs.myMaxlength);
      function fromUser(text) {
          if (text.length > maxlength) {
            var transformedInput = text.substring(0, maxlength);
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
            ngModelCtrl.$render();
            return transformedInput;
          } 
          return text;
      }
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
    }
  }; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! . But here we can enter the input more than 15 characters and later we are taking the substring from it based on specified length. But is it a way to make sure that the user cannot enter more than 15 characters (in this case). ?My goal is to make sure that the user should not enter more than specified length